# What's the official name of a "domain\username" authentication method for a domain?

Tags: authentication, ldap, windows-authentication, openldap

Does anyone know what the official name is for a "domain\username" based login?

I'm trying to troubleshoot an application which claims to have support for LDAP integration with OpenLDAP, Sun One etc.

When I reviewed logs , and sniffed the network traffic I could see that in every instance of authentication a "domain\username" is passed. I'm not 100% sure but I think that method for authentication is only for Active Directory?

Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to provide ;)

Answer (score 1):

"Windows authentication"

Answer (score 0):

[Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory), now part of the greater [Active Directory Domain Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362244(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bit confusing because active directory is capable of authenticating with multiple authentication mechanisms.  Which capability is used is based on domain policy and client capabilities.  So AD could be authenticating with Kerberos, or NTLM or LDAP bind.  Usually Kerberos is preferred.

So maybe your application in question is multi-protocol capable and because it is operating in an AD domain it is defaulting to Kerberos, but if it were operating in an LDAP only environment it would default to LDAP bind.

Answer (score 0):

I believe these "domain\username" logins are NTLM logins.

Answer (score 0):

Domain\username is usually managed by AD and usually based on NTLM authentication.If your application claims it can integrate with OpenLDAP then it doesn't mean it is using LDAP based authentication.It could mean it can synchronize its users and changes with an OpenLDAP based system and it might be having some APIs for this.